# How to handle states with backward and forward browser buttons

Tags: reactjs

I have different color for header for each page and when I use backward or forward button the state is same. I need to change it.

```
const [headerColor, setHeaderColor] = useState("#00eeff");
<header
   className="row row-header"
   style={{ backgroundColor: headerColor }}
>
  <Link
     to="/"
     onClick={() => {
        setHeaderColor("#00eeff");
     }}
  >
    PAGE1
  </Link>
</div>
```

I am wondering about useEffect and

```
history.back | history.forward
```

and use if for every page. Do you think it's good idea or do you know the best solution?

Comment: You could define a color map and apply some logic in your header component to figure out what route path is currently matched and set the color accordingly. Then you won't rely on links to correctly set/update the color. What routing/navigation package is being used?

Comment: react-router-dom and BrowserRouter